# Unable to send successful WFS request to Geoserver to remote host

Tags: python, geoserver

I use Python Requests in order to edit/add spatial data stored in a postgis and served through geoserver.

In the geoserver I have two different stores. One which connects to the server (host is localhost; the server the app runs) and another one with another IP address.

Also the schema is different for each store (one is public).

Everything works fine when I try to send a POST request and edit the location of some point which is stored in the localhost database. But when I try to do the same for points stored in the remote database although I get a success response (200), the edits/additions don't take place.

I was wondering if this is related with the different schema name. Or because the store has a different host. Although that should be handled by geoserver.

Any ideas what can it be the issue?

**EDIT**

This is part of the logfile from geoserver:

```
   Request: getServiceInfo
   2016-09-26 17:01:52,588 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
   org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
   at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:111)
   at     org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:170) ...
```

And this is the XML request I sent:

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
 xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
<wfs:Update typeName="geonode:wld_poi_warehouses_wfp_1">
  <wfs:Property>
   <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>
    <wfs:Value>
     <gml:Point>
       <gml:pos>48.4583518828 -2.109375</gml:pos>
     </gml:Point>
   </wfs:Value>
 </wfs:Property>
 <ogc:Filter>
   <ogc:FeatureId fid="wld_poi_warehouses_wfp_1.2"/>
  </ogc:Filter>
 </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

Comment: is there anything in the log file? please add the exact request sent to the server

Comment: @iant the log file of geoserver doesnt help me a lot in this case. I have included the xml request I sent.

Comment: turn logging up to developer level and try again